# In C I am getting an "error: expected expression before ')' token" on compile

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm guessing that this is going to be a really obvious and simple solution.

```
int is_full() {
  return (top == STACK_SIZE);
}
```

The issue could be that 'STACK_SIZE' is a macro declared on compilation simply by entering -DSTACK_SIZE=10. That 10 can be something else. I'm unsure how to handle that, or if I'm declaring it right, or need to declare it inside the program as well.

Comment: Show us the definition of `STACK_SIZE`. I'll bet you have a semicolon, something like `#define STACK_SIZE 100;`

Comment: @op Is it possible to compile with -E to see the generated code ?

Comment: I just added that info. I've never used macros, so I assumed you can just declare it in compilation? Is there something to declare in the code itself as well?

Comment: Please show us the full command line you used to compile.

Comment: It means you need to go where `STACK_SIZE` is defined and remove the `=`. It should be `#define STACK_SIZE (10)`

Comment: @WhozCraig I think he wants to use the -D flag in the Makefile (I notice a -D in front of STACK_SIZE) instead of defining that symbol in the code.... I think he should post also the Makefile as well :). He should use a default value in the code in any case to avoid this error

Comment: @Jekyll ok that makes heaps more sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why would you put 10 in brackets?

Comment: Perhaps quoting the -D... helps in order to protect it from the shell when the gcc command line is executed. Not sure whether some shells/cmd get confused by a =.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Force of habit. I paren-surround *everything* when specifying macros, mostly from an argument mind-set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a macro from a Makefile. I assume this looking at the -D in front of STACK_SIZE=>

`-DSTACK_SIZE=10`. I assume also that you are using something like gcc because Visual Studio for example uses `\D` to define macros. This way to define the Macro as you can see above is not portable.

The macro can be defined also in the code. In this case you need to write

```
#define STACK_SIZE (10)
```

without using the '=' symbol. This method is portable, by the way the first form is often preferred when you have to change value depending on configurations as it doesn't require to change the code. In any case the code you wrote cannot be compiled if

-DSTACK_SIZE=10 isn't properly declared in the Makefile so, if you choose to use the Makefile definition, you need to protect your code by the weird errors you posted doing something like this:

```
#ifndef STACK_SIZE
    /* handle with a default value o with the macro #error */
#else
    return (top == STACK_SIZE);
#endif
```

Obviously in your case you made some mistake on the Makefile, infact the STACK_SIZE is not defined and you get that return(==); error that you could simply avoid (or manage) with the instructions shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You think STACK_SIZE is being defined, but its not.

the compiler sees:

```
int is_full() {
  return (top == );
}
```

figure out why the #define is not going through.

Comment: You are correct, it is not defined, but I don't think would be a define, infact, as you can see from the -D in the front he is using a Makefile defined Macro... I should say he is trying to use, because he is not actually defining it.